# iPhone - getting the size of a view in pixels

Tags: iphone, uiview, size, pixel, retina-display

I have a camera taken picture, and I'd like to resize it to the exact size of a view. But... bounds.size on an iPhone 4 does not take account of the retina display.

I'd like a code that can give me the real pixel size of the view, so it can work on any device **without having to test / to know the kind of hardware it runs on**.

Do you know how I may do this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every view has the `contentScaleFactor` property, which is typically 1.0 (3G, 3GS, iPad) or 2.0 (retina screens). Another approach is to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`, which has the same values.

**note** to remain compatible with iOS versions prior to 4.0, you have to check if the method is available using `respondsToSelector:@selector(contentScaleFactor)` before getting the value.